# Recursively build a list based on condition

Tags: c#, sql

I have a list of Orders that contains subOrders and so on. These are linked via the ChildOrderID and OrderID. However, within each order there are Products and child products that are linked via the PID and ParentPID. Not every product however has a child product.

I have attached an example screenshot of the data in the db to illustrate what I mean and what I hope to achieve. The issue I'm having is that I need to take this flat file structure and put it into a nested c# list. Each BOMLineClass has a list of BOMLinesClass

```
var navigationItems = bomline.Select(
                        i => new BOMLineClass
                        {
                            ParentOrderID = i.ParentOrderID,
                            BSOOrderNo = i.BSOOrderNo,
                            BSODemandDate = i.BSODemandDate,
                            OrderTypeDesc = i.OrderTypeDesc,
                            OrderType = i.OrderType,
                            BuildRef = i.BuildRef,
                            HasSubAssembly = i.HasSubAssembly,
                            ChildOrderID= i.ChildOrderID,
                            ChildOrderNo= i.ChildOrderNo,
                            OrderID = i.OrderID,
                            OrderLineID = i.OrderLineID,
                            ProductCode = i.ProductCode,
                            ParentPID = i.ParentPID,
                            PID = i.PID,
                        }
                    ).ToList();

                        foreach (var i in navigationItems)
                        {
                            i.BOMLines = navigationItems.Where(n => n.ChildOrderID== i.OrderID).ToList();

                            foreach (var x in i.BOMLines)
                            {
                                //Thought I could link the children via the product ID and parent product Id here
                            }

                        }

                        List<BOMLineClass> rootNavigationItems2 = navigationItems.Where(n => n.ChildOrderID == false).ToList();

                        bh.BOMLines = rootNavigationItems2;
```

I've been struggling with this for at least 5 days now.

[image: DB structure]

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if following works.  You have to start at leafs where ChildOrderID is null and work your way up to root.  You also need to have siblings and children nodes.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("ChildOrderID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ChildOrderNo", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderLineID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ParentPID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(null, null, 40551, 193085, "BP6FS", 261649, 303032);
            dt.Rows.Add(null, null, 40551, 193086, "HT1-BP", 299119, 303032);
            dt.Rows.Add(40551, "BSOMSO20022DDT_1_2", 40550, 193083, "AG947", 253420, 290961);
            dt.Rows.Add(40551, "BSOMSO20022DDT_1_2", 40550, 193084, "JS10", 303032, 290961);
            dt.Rows.Add(40550, "BSOMSO20022DDT_1", 40549, 193081, "CA9680", 266226, 269143);
            dt.Rows.Add(40550, "BSOMSO20022DDT_1", 40549, 193082, "FU552-BP", 290961, 3269143);

            List<BOMLineClass> navigationItems = BOMLineClass.GroupBOM(dt);
            foreach (BOMLineClass order in navigationItems)
            {
                BOMLineClass.Print(order, 0);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

 
    }
    public class BOMLineClass
    {
        public int ParentOrderID { get;set;}
        public string BSOOrderNo { get;set;}
        public DateTime BSODemandDate { get;set;}
        public string OrderTypeDesc { get;set;}
        public string OrderType { get;set;}
        public string BuildRef { get;set;}
        public string HasSubAssembly { get;set;}
        public int? ChildOrderID { get;set;}
        public string ChildOrderNo { get;set;}
        public int OrderID { get;set;}
        public int OrderLineID { get;set;}
        public string ProductCode { get;set;}
        public int ParentPID { get;set;}
        public int PID { get; set; }
        public List<BOMLineClass> children { get; set; }
        public List<BOMLineClass> siblings { get; set; }

        static DataTable dt;
        public static List<BOMLineClass> GroupBOM(DataTable dt)
        {
            BOMLineClass.dt = dt;
            List<BOMLineClass> leafOrders = new List<BOMLineClass>();

            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int?>("ChildOrderID") == null))
            {
                leafOrders.Add(AddFields(row));
            }
            return GroupBOMRecursive(leafOrders); 

        }
        static List<BOMLineClass> GroupBOMRecursive(List<BOMLineClass> childOrders)
        {
            List<BOMLineClass> orders = new List<BOMLineClass>();

            var groups = childOrders.GroupBy(x => x.OrderID).ToList();
            Boolean hasParents = false;

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                //find parent datarow
                List<DataRow> parentRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int?>("ChildOrderID") == group.Key).ToList();
                if (parentRow.Count == 0)
                {
                    //no parent
                    orders.Add(group.First());
                }
                else
                {
                    hasParents = true;
                    BOMLineClass order = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < parentRow.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            order = AddFields(parentRow[i]);
                            order.children = new List<BOMLineClass>();
                            order.children.AddRange(group);
                            orders.Add(order);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (order.siblings == null) order.siblings = new List<BOMLineClass>();
                            order.siblings.Add(AddFields(parentRow[i]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hasParents)
            {
                return GroupBOMRecursive(orders);
            }
            else
            {
                return orders;
            }
        }
        static public BOMLineClass AddFields(DataRow row)
        {
            BOMLineClass order = new BOMLineClass();
            order.ChildOrderID = row.Field<int?>("ChildOrderID");
            order.ChildOrderNo = row.Field<string>("ChildOrderNo");
            order.OrderID = row.Field<int>("OrderID");
            order.OrderLineID = row.Field<int>("OrderLineID");
            order.ProductCode = row.Field<string>("ProductCode");
            order.PID = row.Field<int>("PID");
            order.ParentPID = row.Field<int>("ParentPID");
            return order;
        }

        public static void Print(BOMLineClass order, int level)
        {
            const int IDENT = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}({2})", new string('-', IDENT * level), order.OrderID, order.ParentPID);
            if (order.siblings != null)
            {
                foreach (BOMLineClass sibling in order.siblings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}({2})", new string('-', IDENT * level), sibling.OrderID, sibling.ParentPID);
                }
            }
            if (order.children != null)
            {
                foreach (BOMLineClass child in order.children)
                {
                    Print(child, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
   }
 
 
}
```

Comment: Would this take into account the ParentPID and PID as well?

Comment: Hopefully.  The ParentPID and PID is not complete in the picture you provided.  IDs are missing.   So I do not know.  Basically I'm showing how to recursively go from a leaf up to the root.  So I'm finding top of the hierarchy.  When there is no parent I move the child to the current level of hierarchy and then move up one level until I stop finding parents.

Comment: I added a Print method so you can check.

Comment: Thank you!! This saved me a lot of time and really helped a lot.